# Regex for multiple email Address Validation

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I want to validate email inputs on my app with regex in Angular. But there is a problem,  I want a multiple email validation with regex that user just can enter the email like that

Examples:

```
*****@zigurat.com 
*****@test.com 
*****@partlastic.com
```

**** can be anything but after @ required with multiple email like UP

can you help me with multiple email validation in Angular with regex

thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test against multiple fixed domains using the following construction

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@((zigurat\.com)|(test\.com)|(partlastic\.com))$
```

The part in front of the `@` follows the [JavaScript- and Perl-compatible regular expression for email addresses](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address).